# TAPI: Is it a dead technology?

Tags: 64-bit, tapi

Is there such a thing as a TAPI implementation on 64-bit?  Or am I stuck in the 32-bit land forever?

Is there a viable replacement for TAPI out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TAPI (Telephony Application Programming Interface) hasn't really been updated since 3.1, and that was a while back.  You should still be able to work with it on a 64-bit system though (at the worst case in a 32-bit app though).  Are you running into specific problems?

I think one of the main reasons TAPI hasn't been updated is that a) it evolved to apoint that it works, and b) modern telephony applications and newer features are often more VOIP-oriented than sitting on raw telephony hardware.

http://www.asterisk.org/ is "[open source] software that turns an ordinary computer into a voice communications server."  This VOIP type of situation is where a lot of modern telephony attention is.

Comment: I'm researching TAPI again after not looking at it for some years and I'm finding a deserted wasteland out here. I've looked at asterisk and related forks for PBX solutions, but for scalability and to avoid hardware dependencies I started looking to the cloud last year, and I found Twilio. See a comment that I just posted about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203211/replacement-technology-for-tapi/6485541#6485541). The more I see about the current state of TAPI, the more I'm thinking about just forgetting about putting all the smarts on a PC. HTH